# How to structure pdf header(top-left and top-right) with complex html and styles with PDFRreactor?

Tags: html, css, pdf-reader, css-paged-media

I am using PDFReactor to generate pdfs. What is the best way to structure top of pdf using @top-left and @top-right with complex html tags like `<a>` tag instead of simple raw text like `@top-right{content: "some text"}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `running()` and `element()`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#running-elements.